# Sony, Camera Remote API

Tags: sony

I have a Sony Alpha 5000 ILCE-5000 camera and I've been working on a web project with it. I haven't had any problem integrating that camera using JSON through wifi, but I don't want to depend on wifi camera. Is it possible for my web project to connect to the camera through USB like a remote camera control program?

I read the documentation but it's related to how to connect the camera via wifi using JSON to an Android app.

Answer (score 2):

The Camera Remote API is based on HTTP and JSON like you mentioned and is only available over Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

USB supports different API on some Sony cameras if you set the USB mode to "PC Remote". gphoto2 allows you to take pictures and change few settings for example on A6000, A77m2, A7. A7ii and A77m2 support laos LiveView but only in Capture One and RCC Droid (I do not know of  full featured open library for the USB API)