# qx1 control via usb

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Its great that qx1 has an http API, been looking for a camera like this for years, but is it possible to use the API over wired USB connection? In our scenario the camera will always be connected to the PC via USB for 24/7 operation anyway (to supply power), so using USB for communication would make more sense for us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sony, Camera Remote API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004721/sony-camera-remote-api)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about camera hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg,

I was searching for an answer to the same question as you although my reasons for USB are different. Regardless, I found a post here on stackoverflow that may address your issue. His question is slightly different but I believe the answer provided will apply for you. The link is:

[Sony, Camera Remote API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26004721/4237051)

If I understand correctly from that post, the answer is no, you can't use USB. Hope this is helpful.

Regards,
Dave

Comment: Thanks, its a bit disappointing. Can't be too hard to make that functionality available on Sony's part, bit looks like they only have one scenario in mind. We'd be buying 100s, potentially 1000s of those cameras if they were reliable enough, but that simply can not be accomplished over wifi.