# Can I access Sony Camera using Camera Remote API beta over USB?

Tags: camera, sony-camera-api

I understand that I cannot use Camera Remote API beta to access Sony Cameras using USB. Is there any other API available? I found that somebody has already posted a question regarding this on another Sony camera api forum which is closed now. Please let me know.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004721/sony-camera-remote-api

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use Camera Remote API beta via USB. The Camera Remote API is based on HTTP and JSON and is only available over Wi-Fi.

*The API itself is http/JSON based so it is platform independent so the only issue would be connecting by WiFi.*

Ref: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/